# Bug creating a grid of view components using react native flexbox styling

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I'm trying to create a 5x5 grid of boxes in react native using flexbox. Currently my code is only producing a single row of the grid and I don't know why.

Here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

class Board extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
          <View style={styles.box}></View>
          <View style={styles.box}></View>
          <View style={styles.box}></View>
          <View style={styles.box}></View>
          <View style={styles.box}></View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
          <View style={styles.box}></View>
          <View style={styles.box}></View>
          <View style={styles.box}></View>
          <View style={styles.box}></View>
          <View style={styles.box}></View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
          <View style={styles.box}></View>
          <View style={styles.box}></View>
          <View style={styles.box}></View>
          <View style={styles.box}></View>
          <View style={styles.box}></View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
          <View style={styles.box}></View>
          <View style={styles.box}></View>
          <View style={styles.box}></View>
          <View style={styles.box}></View>
          <View style={styles.box}></View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
          <View style={styles.box}></View>
          <View style={styles.box}></View>
          <View style={styles.box}></View>
          <View style={styles.box}></View>
          <View style={styles.box}></View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
  },
  rowContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
  },
  box: {
    flex: 1,
    height: 60,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: 'black',
  }
});

export default Board;
```

Here's the output:
[image]

How can I make my code output a 5x5 grid of boxes?

Thank you

Comment: I might miss something here, though shouldn't the `container` and `rowContainer` rules have `display: flex`? .... Also the `container` being the main flexbox container, its `flex: 1` doesn't do anything

Comment: Hm.. Interesting question. Also you can try this [simple flexbox grid for react](https://github.com/abraztsov/ReactSimpleFlexGrid) that I found helpful like alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Removing flex: 1 from rowContainer fixed the problem though I'm not entirely sure why

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `borderWidth` and different `borderColor`s on the `container` and `rowContainer`s, it will help you visualize and better understand how flexBox is rendering each parent/child component

Answer (score 0):

You could try this one

```
import React, {
  Component
} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';

class Sudoku extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      sudoku : [
        [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
        [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
        [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
        [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
        [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
        [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
        [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
        [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
        [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
      ]
    }
  }

  increment = (v, i) => {
    let newBoard = [...this.state.sudoku];
    newBoard[v][i]++
    if (newBoard[v][i] === 10) {
      newBoard[v][i] = 0
    }
    this.setState({
      sudoku: newBoard
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {
          this.state.sudoku.map((item, v) => {
            return (
              <View style={styles.row} key={v}>
                {
                  item.map((num, i) => {
                    return (
                    <TouchableHighlight key={i} onPress={() => this.increment(v, i)}>
                      <View style={styles.box}>
                        <Text>{num}</Text>
                      </View>
                    </TouchableHighlight>)
                  })
                }
              </View>
            )
          })
        }
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    margin: 1
  },
  box: {
    width: 40,
    height: 40,
    backgroundColor: 'orange',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    margin : 1,
    borderRadius: 5
  }
});


export default Sudoku;
```